# asp.net core 2.0 use dropzonejs on partialview and componentview

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dropzone.js

I'm trying to use dropzone.js in a viewcomponent and in a partialview and in none works, it looks like the image below:
[image]

nothing happens if you click, and you can not drag any image.

below my ViewComponent

```
@model IEnumerable<PetAlerta.Domain.Entities.Produtosimg>
<script src="~/js/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>
<form action="/file-upload"
      class="dropzone"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

and my PartialView calling component:

```
<div id="imagens" class="tab-pane">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("DropZone", new { codprod = Model.Cod.ToString() })
</div>
```

I have tried to put the dropzone form directly in the partialview and call the js file also in the partialview, but the result is the same.

Only works if I put the dropzone form directly in the main view and call the js file also in the main view, how can I do this using a ViewComponent?

Thanks!